# How to retrieve the network adapter link speed?

Tags: ndis, windows-embedded-compact

I want to determine the link speed of a Ethernet adapter in a Windows CE environment. The actual version of the OS is WEC2013 supporting NDIS6.

The miniport driver provides the OID_GET_LINK_SPEED at the MiniportQueryInformation function. But I can't directly open the driver from a user-mode program.

How can I query information from a miniport driver in a normal program?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to achieve is getting the link speed of a network adapter, then, rather than querying OIDs, the [GetIfEntry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee493262.aspx) API is probably the way to go. The returned [MIB_IFROW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee493426.aspx) structure indicates the link speed, link status, and various statistics associated with the adapter.

To get this information directly from the miniport, use the standard Windows CE NDISUIO driver. If this driver is not available on the device you are using, and you are unable to modify the OS image (by adding SYSGEN_NDISUIO and rebuilding), then use GetIfEntry as described above.

As your driver supports OID_GEN_LINK_SPEED it is likely to be an NDIS5.x implementation (the NDIS6 stack in WEC2013 implements an NDIS5.x interface as well, allowing the use of NDIS5.x drivers). As another aside, true NDIS6 miniports support [OID_GEN_LINK_STATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg155616.aspx) instead of OID_GEN_LINK_SPEED.

Here's an example demonstrating how to obtain the link speed by querying OID_GEN_LINK_SPEED directly. Note the returned link speed is in 100 bps units.

```
#include <ndis.h>
#include <nuiouser.h>

// ...

void GetLinkSpeed()
{
    HANDLE hNdisUio = CreateFile(
        NDISUIO_DEVICE_NAME,
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        NULL
    );

    NDISUIO_QUERY_OID query = { 0 };
    query.Oid = OID_GEN_LINK_SPEED;
    query.ptcDeviceName = L"NE20001"; // Adapter name

    DeviceIoControl(
        hNdisUio,
        IOCTL_NDISUIO_QUERY_OID_VALUE,
        &query,
        sizeof(query),
        &query,
        sizeof(query),
        NULL,
        NULL
    );

    CloseHandle(hNdisUio);

    DWORD speed = *((DWORD *)query.Data) * 100;
    RETAILMSG(1, (L"Link speed: %u bps\r\n", speed));
}
```

Comment: So with that approach I have to change the device and add a new driver NDISUIO to it? Is there a way to omit this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know any alternatives to ndisuio. But are you sure it's not already included in your device? If you are able to modify the OS image, all you need to do is add SYSGEN_NDISUIO in Platform Builder.

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't have the possebility to modify the OS. I have just a simple application that should report some information including the link speed.

Comment: NDISUIO is a standard Windows CE component, so there's a chance the device maker might have already included it in the OS image.

Comment: Yes, I am. It's definitly not in there. NDISUIO requires a DLL at the device and a registry key to load it. Both are absent.